# Do I have to use specific coroutine dispatcher when updating data in DataStore?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-datastore

For **Retrofit**, **Room** we just call `viewModelScope.launch { ... }` and they automatically do requests in background thread

But when I tried to update the model in **DataStore** it didn't work, though there was no runtime exception, that's why I thought everything should be fine, but no, it's still the default model

```
val Context.userDataStore: DataStore<User> by dataStore(
    fileName = USER_FILE_NAME,
    serializer = UserSerializer
)

private object UserSerializer : Serializer<User> {
    override val defaultValue: User
        get() = User()

...
```

Then I tried to update with specific context and it worked

`viewModelScope.launch { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... } }`

So this is the right way for **DataStore**?

Comment: Have you found the confirmation that we need to define `Dispatcher` for DataStore? I can only see `private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())` in `SingleProcessDataStore` source code but this info should be in docs...

Answer (score -2):

> **Caution**: Avoid blocking threads on DataStore data reads whenever possible.
> Blocking the UI thread can cause ANRs or UI jank, and blocking other
> threads can result in deadlock.

in DataStore docs is mentioned that if you're working with an existing codebase that uses synchronous disk I/O or if you have a dependency that doesn't provide an asynchronous API.

Kotlin coroutines provide the `runBlocking()` coroutine builder to help bridge the gap between synchronous and asynchronous code.

You can use `runBlocking()` to read data from DataStore synchronously.

```
val exampleData = runBlocking { context.dataStore.data.first() }
```

Performing synchronous I/O operations on the UI thread can cause ANRs or UI jank. You can mitigate these issues by asynchronously preloading the data from DataStore:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        context.dataStore.data.first()
        // You should also handle IOExceptions here.
    }
}
```

This way, DataStore asynchronously reads the data and caches it in memory. Later synchronous reads using `runBlocking()` may be faster or may avoid a disk I/O operation altogether if the initial read has completed.

[DataStore docs.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#kotlin)

Comment: Did you just randomly answered it? It has no relation to the question